# How would you describe romanticism to a 14 years old?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Well, the question is pretty clear. How would you describe romanticism to a 14 years old?

Comment: The discovery of the beauty of nature.

Comment: Can you say something about why this just wouldn't fall from restating the definition in a way a 14-year-old would understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One source I can direct you to is a very helpful video on the history of romanticism.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiRWBI0JTYQ&index=6&list=PLwxNMb28XmpdJpJzF2YRBnfmOva0HE0ZI

As the information at the bottom states,

> "Romanticism is a historical movement that still hugely colours how we tend to feel and look at the world: it’s responsible for the way we approach love, nature, business and children."

For me, that is the best opportunity to explain the concept of romanticism to anyone not familiar with the history of philosophy.